# Read the values from nested string

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, nested-loops

I am reading a file which has data as below.

> {1 2 3{4 5 6{7 8 9}10 11}12 13 14 ......}

The output should be

> 1 2 3 12 13 14 4 5 6 10 11 7 8 9

.There will be many inner structures like this.

We are reading line by line from the file. The inner groups may start and end at anywhere (starts at line 1 and ends at line 5. So we need to check all lines in the file).

I tried using Array-List of List for each inner group but it is not working because we have some data after the completion of inner loop as well which should come before the inner group.

Taking count with braces and using nested for loops can work but it affects the performance. Can you please let me know if any better approach is there. End result should be one list with the above mentioned order.

Comment: Did you consider a tree? Each brace could be a new subtree...

Comment: You have a code problem. Consider posting the code you wrote so far that causes that problem. Of course you can use lists to solve this problem; it all depends on your implementation.

Comment: @IQV: If we are iterating from outer to inner, then we can implement easily. But in our case, after iterating an inner group we have some data outer to that which should go before inner group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a `Stack` as shown

```
    String str = "{1 2 3{4 5 6{7 8 9}10 11}12 13 14}";
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    Stack<StringBuilder> temp = new Stack<>();
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        switch(c){
            case '{':
                if(!temp.isEmpty())temp.peek().append(",");
                temp.push(new StringBuilder());
                break;
            case '}':
                if(!temp.isEmpty())temp.peek().append(",");
                res.insert(0,temp.pop());
                break;
            case ' ':
                temp.peek().append(",");
                break;
            default:
                temp.peek().append(c);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(res); //1,2,3,12,13,14,4,5,6,10,11,7,8,9,
```

Everytime `{` is encountered with create a new `StringBuilder` to read the numbers. Once `}` is found we pop and output the result. This can be optimized with `regex` to read the range characters at a time rather than single character at a time.

Comment: If the input is like the example which i have given in question, it is working fine. But my actual input will be a file with thousands of lines. In this case, i  cannot read the whole file at a stretch and covert it to string because it consumes lot of memory. So i have to read the file line by line which is the problem with above approach.

Comment: One approach could be to wrap it inside a `while` loop so `str = readLine()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable for you. I am playing around with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), a HTML Parser, for my own projects and came up with this idea. First replace all opening braces with opening div tag and all closing braces with closing div tag. Then append the ownTexts of a div starting from the outer div. Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){                       
        String html = "{1 2 3 {4 5 6 {7 8 9}10 11}12 13 14}";
        html = html.replaceAll("\\{", "<div>").replaceAll("\\}", "</div>");    
        System.out.println(html);

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);            
        Elements es = doc.select("div");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Element e :es){
            sb.append(e.ownText());
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
// 1 2 3 12 13 14 4 5 6 10 11 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks Eritrean. I think it should work. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to split the string at each { or } and join the first element of the array with the last, the second with the second last and so on. Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){                       
        String str = "{1 2 3{4 5 6{7 8 9}10 11}12 13 14}";
        String [] splited = str.replaceFirst("\\{", "").split("\\{|\\}");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0, j = splited.length-1;i<j;i++,j--){
            sb.append(splited[i]).append(" ").append(splited[j]).append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(splited[splited.length/2 ]);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Comment: If the input is like the example which i have given in question, it is working fine. But my actual input will be a file with thousands of lines. In this case, i  cannot read the whole file at a stretch and covert it to string because it consumes lot of memory. So i have to read the file line by line which is the problem with above approach.